# Holding plywood between bars for shelves?

Tags: wood, screws, woodworking, outdoor

I have a small balcony that has wrought iron bars on either side. The width between the bars is about 5ft. I wanted to place several 1"x6" plywood pieces between the bars for some small plants.

In other words, the iron bars on either side would act as the columns for the shelves. The problem is I'm not sure how to hold the shelves to the columns.

My question: without welding or damaging the iron bars, what's an inexpensive way to place the plywood between the iron bars?

The keyword here is "inexpensive" because if it's too much, then I might as well buy a shelf set.

Here's what I was thinking of:

[image]

Comment: Do you own the balcony?

Comment: Do not do it. You risk the chance to bend/damage the wrought iron, which is softer than typical steel. The 5' span with weight will cause huge bending force and distortion on the posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't need to hold much weight a cheap way would be to use a U bolt and U bracket.
[image][image]

Attach the U bolt to the vertical pipe, with the U bracket held behind it and screwed to the sheet.

A bit stronger, and probably not much more money, would be a shelf bracket held on by two hose clamps. This would allow several screws into the wood.

[image][image]

If you want to get fancier there are special clamps of all sorts for fastening things to metal tubes.  Search for example for temporary handrail hardware.

Here's an example of one that is very expensive.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps also good to protect the iron from any scratches, scuffs and indents caused by hanging hardware, e.g. by wrapping rubber padding around the iron where the clamp is applied